# How to change the background of multiple buttons when reading from Session Storage

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all the buttons on this page begin neutral and then turn red when the page loads and finally turn green whenever a checklist on the next page is completed. I can only seem to get the first button to work but the others aren't doing anything. Any advice? All other attempts are in the comments.

```
    function initial(){
        if (localStorage.getItem("run") == null) {

            /*  var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
                var idObject = {};

                idObject[form.elements[0].id].("false");
                for(var i = 1; i < form.length ; i++){
                     idObject[form.elements[i].id].push("false");
                }   
                sessionStorage.setItem("savedIds",JSON.stringify(idObject)); */

            /*  var ids = [ {area:"kitchen",done:"true"},
                            {area:"livingroom",done:"false"},
                            {area:"bathroom",done:"false"},
                            {area:"dining",done:"false"},
                            {area:"bredroom",done:"false"}]; */

            /*  var ids = {"kitchen":false,
                            "livingroom":true,
                            "bathroom":false,
                            "dining":false,
                            "bedroom":false};   */

                var ids = [false,false,false,false,false];          
                sessionStorage.setItem("savedIds",JSON.stringify(ids)); 

            localStorage.setItem("run", true);
        }
    }

        function loader(){
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        var obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("savedIds"));

        for(var i = 0;i < 5;i++){
            if(obj[i] == true){
                document.getElementById(form.elements[i].id).style.backgroundColor = "green";
                return false;
            }else{
                document.getElementById(form.elements[i].id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

So I have mentioned this on the forum but I haven't been able to quite solve this. It is killing me since I have spent days on this alone. Any advice would be great!

Something to note, this is the function on the checklist page that reads the checklist and turns the buttons to green. There is also an issue where the color doesn't change the green because of a "VM915:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 4"

```
 function checkTasks(form){
        var count = 0;
        for(var i = 0;i<form.task.length;i++){
            if(form.task[i].checked){
                count++;
            }
        }

        if(count == form.task.length){
            var obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("savedIds"));
            obj[0] = true;
            sessionStorage.setItem("savedIds",obj);
            //sessionStorage.setItem("kitchen","true");
            window.open("http://localhost:8080/Project/home.html","_self");
        }else{
            alert("You have not completed all the tasks! Please check all the boxes to indicate you have completed the tasks. If there is an issue, write it in the other box.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, Looks like you've combined android java with javascript. They both are different. Look here to get started in javascript https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: Oh, I just realized I left some code in there that I was trying out. Should be gone now!

Comment: The problem with your code is architectural. You need to manage the state of the button, update that state and then manipulate your CSS based on the state coming from your secondary page. It looks like you're using persistent `localStorage` - you could make that work for managing state but that's not ideal.

Comment: Also, why are you using JSON.stringify on an array? It is not an object and then you are doing JSON.parse on an array string which is why you get the error.

Comment: Ok, so I should I go about managing all of the button in one function? Also, that means if I change all the true and false to "true" and "false", it could work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function initial(){
        if (localStorage.getItem("unitrun") === null) {
            var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
            var tot = form.length;

            for(var i = 0; i < tot ; i++){
                sessionStorage.setItem(form.elements[i].id,"false");
            }
        localStorage.setItem("unitrun", true);
        }
    }

    function loader(){
        var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
        var tot = form.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < tot ; i++){
            if(sessionStorage.getItem(form.elements[i].id) === "true"){
                document.getElementById(form.elements[i].id).disabled = true;
            }else{
                document.getElementById(form.elements[i].id).disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

function checkTasks(form){
        var count = 0;
        var list = document.getElementById("tasks").getElementsByTagName("li");
        var tot = list.length;
        for(var i = 0;i < tot;i++){
            if(form.task[i].checked){
                count++;
            }
        }

        if(count == tot){
            sessionStorage.setItem("kitchen","true");
            window.open("http://localhost:8080/Project/home.html","_self");
        }else{
            alert("You have not completed all the tasks! Please check all the boxes to indicate you have completed the tasks. If there is an issue, write it in the other box.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this (IMO) is maximizing the power of CSS

for example:

CSS

```
button.myBtn {
  color: initial;
}

body.loaded button.myBtn {
  color: red;
}

body.processed button.myBtn {
  color: green;
}
```

Add class `myBtn` to all of the buttons whose color you want to change. Then in your javascript all you need to do is add class `loaded` and class `processed` to document.body to get all of your buttons' colors to change.

Comment: I was going to put almost exactly this, but your answer is more succinct. I suggest adding the javascript to do this, or jQuery.

Comment: Ok, how do I use jQuery to solve this issue? Also, how would the logic for loaded and processed work? Are you suggesting that I continue to store the data as I have been before and then it changed when I call loaded and processed?

Comment: There's no need for jquery to do this. You don't need a whole framework to achieve something like this.